# Fuction if True return list of combination

Tags: python, memoization

I am following a dynamic programming video. However the return is False for the given sets of number show below. It should display [3,4]

If i change the "combo" to True. It will return True. However i want to show the combination instead.

```
combo = list()

def howsum(targetsum,numbers):
    if targetsum == 0: return combo
    if targetsum < 0: return False
    
    for number in numbers:
        remainder = targetsum - number
        combo.append(number)
        
        if howsum(remainder,numbers) == True: return combo
    return False
     
print(howsum(7,[3,4])) #output should be [3,4]
```

Comment: You need to pass a copy of combo to each call to your function. At the moment you are appending too many values to the same list

Comment: You  return False or a list - perhaps you should return None or the list, and check for None/Not None instead of True/False

Comment: Hi Sorry, i dont understand. Can you please explain more on "pass a copy of ombo to each call of my function". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are checking if the return value is True, instead of if it exists. The truthiness of an empty collection is `False` and of a non-empty collection is `True`. Also for backtracking, you need to `pop()` from the current combo to try the alternatives.

```
combo = list()
def howsum(targetsum, numbers):
    if targetsum == 0: return combo
    if targetsum < 0: return False

    for number in numbers:
        remainder = targetsum - number
        combo.append(number)
        if howsum(remainder, numbers): return combo
        combo.pop()
    return False


print(howsum(7, [3, 4]))  # output should be [3,4]
```

One other thing to note. Instead of creating a global `combo` list, we can pass it as a parameter by introducing a helper function.

```
def howsum_helper(targetsum, numbers, combo):
    if targetsum == 0: return combo
    if targetsum < 0: return False

    for number in numbers:
        remainder = targetsum - number
        combo.append(number)
        if howsum_helper(remainder, numbers, combo): return combo
        combo.pop()
    return False

def howsum(targetsum, numbers):
    return howsum_helper(targetsum, numbers, [])

print(howsum(7, [3, 4]))  # output should be [3,4]
```

This solution also assumes that a number in the numbers list can be repeated to reach the `targetSum`.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to understand the pop function and the helper function.

Comment: Hi,if have multiple sets of targets and number, the global combo list will caused the previous set to be pass to next set

eg 
`print(howsum(7,[3,4]) #output [3,4]
print(howsum(8,[2,3,4] # output [3,4,2,2,2,2] # the [3,4 was passdown from the previous output]`

However, the  video  doesnt have the helper. In the code,  The`List`  created when `Sumtarget == 0`. Please advise why the list not clear up everytime the function was called. Can I know is it possible in Python without a helper function?

The code is at time 1:42:54
[link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk&t=6174s